# How to insert space between characters after some specific symbols?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a text file in the following format:

```
\Hollands\\\\\\hOlAnz/hOlAns\\\\\\\\
\Hollandse\\\\\\hOlAns@\\\\\\\\
\Hollywood\\\\\\hOliwud/hOliwut/hOliwYd\\\\\\\\
...
```

and I would like to make it look like this ⬇️:

```
\Hollands\\\\\\h O l A n z / h O l A n s\\\\\\\\
\Hollandse\\\\\\h O l A n s @\\\\\\\\
\Hollywood\\\\\\h O l i w u d / h O l i w u t / h O l i w Y d\\\\\\\\
```

What should I do?
Many thanks in advance.

I tried using sed:

```
sed 's/\{\\\\\\\{1\}\)/\1 /g'
```

as I was expecting to insert`\1 /` (one blank space) after `{1\}`(each one character), after 6 repetitive `\`s.
but got the error saying

```
RE error: invalid repetition count(s)
```

Comment: Note that when you don't pass `-r` to `sed`, it uses BRE rather than ERE syntax. That changes how a backslash is interpreted when it comes before a `{`. Beyond that, though, it's not very clear how the sed command you ran is expected to have your desired behavior.

Comment: Repetition operators are _modifiers_. When ERE syntax is enabled with the `-r` argument to `sed`, `{1}` doesn't mean "any one character", it means "exactly one of the preceding character" (which makes it a no-op, because when you don't specify otherwise, _anything_ is expected to match exactly one of itself). So "exactly one of any character" could be written as `.{1}`, but that's exactly the same as just `.` -- no reason for the `{1}` at all. (When ERE syntax _isn't_ enabled and you're using sed's default of BRE, `{1}` is written as `\{1\}` instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed is the right tool for doing a simple `s/old/new/` operation on individual strings, for anything more than that (e.g. isolating part of a string and then doing further operations on parts of that string as you need), just use awk.

Using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and gensub():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(.*\\{6}.)(.*)(\\{8})/,a) { $0=a[1] gensub(/./," &","g",a[2]) a[3] } 1' file
\Hollands\\\\\\h O l A n z / h O l A n s\\\\\\\\
\Hollandse\\\\\\h O l A n s @\\\\\\\\
\Hollywood\\\\\\h O l i w u d / h O l i w u t / h O l i w Y d\\\\\\\\
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/(\\{6}[^\\])(.*\\{8})/\1 \n\2/;:a;s/\n([^\\])/\1 \n/;ta;s/ \n//' file
```

Turn on extended regexp `-E`.

For all lines,using pattern matching insert a space and unique delimiter (`\n`) the character after six `\`'s.

Iterate replacing the newline and the following character by the following character a space and the newline delimiter until the next occurrence of `\`.

Remove the last space and newline and print the result.